# Upgrade websnap app to delphi 2005 - CoInitialize error

Tags: delphi, ado

We have a current product written in Delphi 6 websnap, which I'm attempting to upgrade to run under delphi 2005.
It uses ADO, and the error on running is "CoInitialize has not been called".
The only references I can find to this error point to IntraWeb and something called ServerController, which I'm not sure is relevant to me.
Any number of calls of CoInitialize(nil) have no effect.

Am I wasting my time getting this to run or is it possible to run under 2005 -or a later release come to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CoInitialize` needs to be called within the thread that does the COM access (e.g. in any thread that accesses your database through ADO).  It is called in the main thread by Delphi by default, but you need to call it explicitly in other threads.

Try calling it in the `OnActivate` event, and call `CoUninitialize` in the `OnDeactivate` event.

Also make sure your ADOTables and ADOConnections are not open at design time. As otherwise the app will try to use COM before you've called `CoInitialize`.

If all else fails - try overriding the web form's constructor and slip a `CoInitialize` in there before you call inherited.  Don't forget to call `CoUninitialize` in the destructor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure what constitutes a thread in websnap. I've tried CoInitialize in various activation events but execution doesn't seem to reach them. Have also tried the initialization section, which does run but doesn't help.

Comment: +1 for Steve's answer, but you could make a simple COM initiliazation unit and put it as the first unit in your project source uses clause. Put the CoInitialize in the initialization section and the CoUninitialize in the finalization section.

Comment: Thank you Stuart, but I've already effectively tried this. I can step through the lines of code that call CoInit, application runs. When I hit the web page 1st time, then it gives me the error. Even if I step using F7, I don't get to see any of my own code. So I think the question is - can WebSnap work with delphi 2005 and ADO at all?

Comment: @Petebr - you've hooked up an event handler to your PageModule.OnActivate, and it doesn't get hit?

Comment: Correct. I have put CoInit and break points in the main page  (WebAppPageModule) and my dataModule (TWebDataModule) on onCreate, onActivate and initialization sections and only the init section is ever reached. Have searched the entire project for open datasets, but nothing is opened until the first request is received, but that code is never reached.

Comment: Looks like it's initialising components on the first page, get's as far as TADOQuery.Create; TADODataset.Create, TADOCommand.Create then the system OLEerror. Have also created a new websnap project in 2005, notice it does  TWebAppSockObjectFactory.Create('... rather than TWebAppAutoObjectFactory.Create(Class_ComWebApp - but it still produced the coinit error. It does however let me step through debug dcu's, not much help though.    Question still remains for a websnap app in 2005, can it work with ADO, and where to put the coinit line. and thanks for the help so far btw!

Comment: As a last-ditch effort - try overriding the web form's constructor and slip a CoInitialize in there before you call inherited.

Comment: I'll add that to the answer so you can accept it :-)  Well done!